# When is a graph balanced bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have a quick question: is there any sufficient condition (theorem, lemma, proposition,...)

to show that a graph (vertices do not have the same degree) is balanced bipartite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No odd cycles (which guarantees that the graph is bipartite) and regular (aka, all vertices have the same degree).

Comment: What if all of vertices do not have the same degree?

Comment: Then, it may or may not be balanced. This was just a sufficient condition. Btw, if you are looking for an algorithm to determine whether a graph is balanced bipartite, then that's easy. Are you looking for such an algorithm?

Comment: Well, to be more precise, I had a bipartite graph $G$ such that its  vertices do not have the same degree. I'm looking for a condition that once it is given, the graph $G$ will be balanced bipartite. I wonder that it may relates to Hall's Marriage Theorem.

Comment: Well, if the graph is bipartite (which is one condition you have to check) and it has a perfect matching, then it will also be balanced. So you could construct such conditions.

Comment: Okay. So now I need some tools to verify whether my graph has a perfect matching or not. Can you suggest any good one?

Comment: You already mentioned Hall's Theorem. If you are looking for "tools" (as in algorithms), then you just as might use an algorithm to answer your question directly, right?

Comment: I look for a "condition" which does not need to be a practical algorithm. Anyway, I would like to see your algorithm. It somehow helps me getting closer the desired answer.

Comment: To [check if a graph is bipartite](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bipartite-graph/) you basically perform a BFS and color the vertices. If the graph is bipartite, checking if it is balanced is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition is that the graph has two vertices.

If instead you want a necessary and sufficient condition, then you will not find any efficient one, because it can be used to solve bin packing which is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if all cycles are even, and if so check if each partition has the same size by partitioning into vertices at even and odd distances from a vertex.

But to efficiently check whether a graph is balanced bipartite, I would prefer to do a greedy 2-coloring and check if $\#$vertices with same color are equal. With efficient data structures (adj lists) this can be done in $O(n+m)$ time.

EDIT: This works for connected graphs only, else as user21820 points out, is NP hard. It is kind of surprising to see that adding a simple constraint makes the problem very difficult (from linear).

Comment: Note that this is also only a sufficient condition since there may be unconnected components.